# list full path of file without tying it from relative relative path

Tags: ls

I could do this

```
root@server [/home/user/public_html]# ls /home/user/public_html/.htaccess
```

but I'd like to do this

```
ls --switch .htaccess
/home/user/public_html/.htaccess
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `find` in combination with `pwd` is a fine answer but it creates two subshells and isn't necessary.  There is a command which will do what you want:

`readlink -f .htaccess`

#### Output

```
$ cd /tmp && touch foo
$ ls ./foo
./foo
$ readlink -f ./foo
/tmp/foo
```

Comment: `find` is not needed, `\`pwd\`` is only one subshell and can be replaced by `$PWD`. `readlink -f` also follows symbolic links, which is not always desired.

Comment: On FreeBSD and MacOSX, this results in the error `readlink: illegal option -- f`. Anyone have the solution for other *BSDs?

Comment: On FreeBSD you can loop over the results from `ls`, calling `realpath` on each one.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to use `find` and `pwd`.

Something like:

```
find `pwd` -name .htaccess -maxdepth 1
```

**OR**

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-list-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux/1427114#1427114):

```
ls -d `pwd`/.htaccess
```

You could use the `$PWD` variable to cut out unwanted subshells:

```
find $PWD -name .htaccess -maxdepth 1
ls -d $PWD/.htaccess
```

See Also:

- [How can I list files with their absolute path in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215)
- [ls -R --fullpath | grep filename](http://my.brandeis.edu/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0002vQ)

Comment: wow I'm surprised that didn't get closed offtopic on SO

Comment: at the time, where else could they ask?

Comment: That doesn't make it on-topic there; it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: i didn't say it was on-topic, just that they might have been more forgiving back then

Answer (score 0):

`realpath` exists for this purpose (finding canonical absolute paths):

```
$ realpath .htaccess
/home/user/public_html/.htaccess
```

Comment: `realpath` has been obsoleted by `readlink -f` in GNU coreutils, so fewer and fewer Linux systems have it. (And `readlink -f` also exists on OpenBSD, so it's not completely Linux-specific.)